# Send progress values from Service to Activity in Android Using Binder

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service downloading some data and I want to send progress values to the activity that's bounded to this service.

I know the available solutions for similar problems: AsyncTask, Messenger and Bounding Activity to a service. I want to implement it using bounded service approach.

All examples I have found make public method in the service and call the method from the activity class after binding it to the service but I think in my situation this will require infinite loop to get the frequent update values. Is there any approach to make the service sends the data to the activity and some how updates the UI when progress value changes ? (Without using Messenger or AsycTask)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear why you wouldn't just use the binding technique.

Comment: I use the binding technique. But the samples I found make the activity call method in the service. this wont be efficient for getting updates from the service because it will require me to frequently check from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a callback in another AIDL.

```
package ...;
interface XService {
    ...
    void startX(String path, XServiceCallback callback);
}
```

and in the other aidl file:

```
package ...;
interface XServiceCallback {
    void xReady(int errCode, String text);
}
```

But the callback will be invoked asynchronously, so you will have to use a Handler.post(Runnable).

An alternative is to use a Runnable that re-posts itself (via *postDelayed()*) on the UI thread and polls the progress, say, each 0.2 seconds.

In both cases you will have to remember that the service or the client may die.

As to the code, you take some remote service example (there is a lot of them in the 'net), and add to the client side something like this:

```
XServiceCallback mServiceCallback = new XServiceCallback.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void xReady(final int errCode, final String text) throws RemoteException {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            // use the result
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Your client passes this callback to the service, the service calls it, your method on the client side gets called.

Comment: Is there another easier way using only Binder class and Connection object in the activity ?

Comment: What will initiate the UI update? If it's the service, you get a callback or a `Messenger` (that boils down to another style of a callback). If it's the client, you get some kind of polling. How will the client know that the operation is complete? Again, it is either a callback or polling.

Comment: how to make this callback without using Messenger ?